# How to use terraform with AWS provider and local editors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emacs, localhost, terraform, editor

When use terraform run tasks with AWS as

```
provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxx"
  }
}

terraform {
  required_version = "1.0.0"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      version = "3.46.0"
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }

  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "my-bucket"
    key            = "my-key"
    region         = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

If only run the `terraform init` and `terraform apply` on a deploy server, but can't do it on localhost because of the aws key security issue. Then every time edit the .tf file with an editor on local with cause this problem:

The language server issue. Both VS Code and Emacs can't get the terraform resources correctly as it didn't do the `terraform init`. Such as Emacs:

`~/.spacemacs` config

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
'(lsp
  git
  (terraform :variables
      terraform-auto-format-on-save t
      terraform-backend 'lsp)
```

In the .tf file it always notices: `Server tfls:3869 exited with status exit(check corresponding stderr buffer for details). Do you want to restart it? (y or n)`.

I found a problem in this buffer: `*lsp-log: tfls:1358*`

```
[Trace - 09:04:46 AM] Sending request 'textDocument/documentLink - (5)'.
Params: {
  "textDocument": {
    "uri": "file:///Users/user12/terraform/module1/main.tf"
  }
}

[Trace - 09:04:47 AM] Received response 'textDocument/documentLink - (5)' in 38ms.
Result: [
  {
    "tooltip": "https://github.com",
    "target": "https://github.com",
    "range": {
      "end": {
        "character": 10,
        "line": 1
      },
      "start": {
        "character": 1,
        "line": 1
      }
    }
  }
]

[Trace - 09:04:58 AM] Received response 'textDocument/documentLink - (13)' in 43ms.
Result: [
  {
    "tooltip": "https://github.com",
    "target": "https://github.com",
    "range": {
      "end": {
        "character": 10,
        "line": 1
      },
      "start": {
        "character": 1,
        "line": 1
      }
    }
  }
]


[Trace - 09:04:58 AM] Received notification 'textDocument/publishDiagnostics'.
Params: {
  "diagnostics": [
    {
      "message": "Resource aws_security_group does not exist",
      "source": "Terraform Schema",
      "severity": 1,
      "range": {
        "end": {
          "character": 29,
          "line": 3
        },
        "start": {
          "character": 9,
          "line": 3
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "Resource aws_security_group_rule does not exist",
      "source": "Terraform Schema",
      "severity": 1,
      "range": {
        "end": {
          "character": 34,
          "line": 17
        },
        "start": {
          "character": 9,
          "line": 17
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "Resource aws_security_group_rule does not exist",
      "source": "Terraform Schema",
      "severity": 1,
      "range": {
        "end": {
          "character": 34,
          "line": 29
        },
        "start": {
          "character": 9,
          "line": 29
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "Resource aws_security_group_rule does not exist",
      "source": "Terraform Schema",
      "severity": 1,
      "range": {
        "end": {
          "character": 34,
          "line": 42
        },
        "start": {
          "character": 9,
          "line": 42
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "uri": "file:////Users/user12/terraform/module1/main.tf"
}
```

Another buffer `*tfls::stderr*`:

```
...
time="2021-06-21T14:24:31+08:00" level=info msg="Log Level is Debug: false"
e[36mINFOe[0m Server started                               
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x14af3fa]

goroutine 28 [running]:
github.com/hashicorp/terraform/configs.(*Module).appendFile(0xc000e7c600, 0x0, 0xc0006b65b8, 0x1101c9d, 0xc000042410)
    /Users/user12/go/1.16.2/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform@v0.12.20/configs/module.go:128 +0x3a
github.com/hashicorp/terraform/configs.NewModule(0xc000847d80, 0xa, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x15)
    /Users/user12/go/1.16.2/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform@v0.12.20/configs/module.go:97 +0x1fa
github.com/juliosueiras/terraform-lsp/langserver.TextDocumentComplete(0x1e7d970, 0xc000bfcb10, 0xc000124000, 0x51, 0x10, 0x15, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /Users/user12/terraform/terraform-lsp/langserver/complete.go:56 +0x48e
reflect.Value.call(0x1b75760, 0x1d10f58, 0x13, 0x1cbed0c, 0x4, 0xc000bfcdb0, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc000bfcdb0, 0x199, ...)
    /Users/user12/.goenv/versions/1.16.2/src/reflect/value.go:476 +0x8e7
reflect.Value.Call(0x1b75760, 0x1d10f58, 0x13, 0xc000bfcdb0, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc000bfcdb0, 0x1)
    /Users/user12/.goenv/versions/1.16.2/src/reflect/value.go:337 +0xb9
github.com/creachadair/jrpc2/handler.newHandler.func7(0x1e7d970, 0xc000bfcb10, 0xc0002d0540, 0x1c38e60, 0xc000bfcb10, 0x1b87280, 0x246a8a0)
    /Users/user12/go/1.16.2/pkg/mod/github.com/creachadair/jrpc2@v0.4.2/handler/handler.go:222 +0x1f4
github.com/creachadair/jrpc2/handler.Func.Handle(0xc0000d23e0, 0x1e7d970, 0xc000bfcb10, 0xc0002d0540, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1e7d970, 0xc000bfcb10)
    /Users/user12/go/1.16.2/pkg/mod/github.com/creachadair/jrpc2@v0.4.2/handler/handler.go:23 +0x44
github.com/creachadair/jrpc2.(*Server).invoke(0xc0001ec240, 0x1e7d8c8, 0xc0002d0580, 0x1e69b60, 0xc0000d23e0, 0xc0002d0540, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /Users/user12/go/1.16.2/pkg/mod/github.com/creachadair/jrpc2@v0.4.2/server.go:288 +0x175
github.com/creachadair/jrpc2.(*Server).dispatch.func1(0xc000c0e814, 0xc0001ec240, 0xc000bdc420)
    /Users/user12/go/1.16.2/pkg/mod/github.com/creachadair/jrpc2@v0.4.2/server.go:185 +0x91
created by github.com/creachadair/jrpc2.(*Server).dispatch
    /Users/user12/go/1.16.2/pkg/mod/github.com/creachadair/jrpc2@v0.4.2/server.go:183 +0x137

Process tfls stderr finished
```

So I think the main reason is terraform didn't do the init.

In this case, how to mock an AWS provider on localhost to use local editor correctly? I found [Local Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs) only works for files. Is there a good way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this `tfls` program and so I can't comment on the cause of the panic, but if it is indeed related to not running `terraform init` as you suspect then one way to proceed could be to initialize without activating the backend:

```
terraform init -backend=false
```

In this mode Terraform should still do all of the usual installation steps (modules and providers) but will skip trying to initialize the S3 backend, and thus it should succeed even though you don't have AWS credentials available.

According to the stack trace this `tfls` program is using code from quite an old version of Terraform, so even once initialized it may not be able to fully understand the Terraform language as supported by Terraform v1.0 and later.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I upgraded the tf version and ran a false backend initialization. Though it didn't resolve the problem completely, something looks better.